# In a New Keynesian model, why do firms not take the interest rate into account when discounting their future profits?

Tags: macroeconomics, interest-rate, new-keynesian-economics, theory-of-the-firm

I understand that firms usually discount future prices using the discount factor $M_t = \beta^t u'(c_t)$. Both the presence of $\beta$ and $u'(c_t)$ make sense to me as they reflect the (im)patience and decreasing marginal utility of the firms owners. However I have trouble understanding why the nominal interest rate does not play any role in the discounting of profits.

I thought that firms maximize their Net Present Value and that this is calculated using the nominal interest rate. Am I wrong in believing that firms maximize their NPV *or* is $M_t$ in some way related to the discounting used when calculating NPV?

For an example of the sort of discount factor I am talking about see p. 4 in this document:
[https://www3.nd.edu/~esims1/new_keynesian.pdf](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eesims1/new_keynesian.pdf)

Comment: Hint: Check the Euler equation.